# How do I use StaticRecsource for brushes in Code-Behind

Tags: c#, livecharts, staticresource

I'm working in a existing application, this app has a ResourceDictionary `ColorResource.xaml` in which custom colorbrushes are made. An example:

```
<Color x:Key="ColorHmiBlue"             A="255" R="151" G="190" B="223" />
<SolidColorBrush  x:Key="ColorValue_3" Color="{StaticResource ColorHmiBlue}" />
```

Normally in xaml you would use `{StaticResource ColorValue_3}` to use the colour.
In Live Charts Code-Behind you'd do:

```
Fill= System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue
```

How can I use the custom colour for this?

Answer (score 1):

First load your resource dictionary and then use its indexer to get the resource:

```
var dict = new ResourceDictionary();
dict.Source = new Uri("/uri/of/the/dictionary", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
var brush = (SolidColorBrush)dict["ColorValue_3"];
```

Alternatively, you can use `Application.Current.Resources` property to access all global resources of your application.